# Gallery Inside One Post

Tags: gallery

For image galleries, I need a code that uses next/previous links to bring you to the next/previous image **in that post** and **keeps the images in the correct order you chose while inserting them into the post**.  (Every major news site seems to have this feature.)

Currently, if you add `<?php next_image_link( false, 'Next Image' ); ?>` and `<?php previous_image_link( false, 'Previous Image' ); ?>` to your image.php or your attachment template in WordPress **the links may bring you to a gallery in a different post if the image is used elsewhere**.

To further illustrate this proble, [take a look at this gallery](http://themeforward.com/demo2/?p=2173).  There are three images.  If you click the penguin and start using prev/next links to scroll through them you'll see additional images which should not be displayed!

**This problem still has been solved.  I had to use the media editor to attach the posts... too bad WP isn't always doing this natively when the image is uploaded.**

Comment: Would you like to display the gallery on your `single.php`? Should the next Image be loaded via AJAX?

Comment: No, I'd like it to take you to an attachment template. Right now, it will bring you to your images out of order and links to images that aren't even associated with the post.

Comment: Those functions above will not enable what your asking for, you need to grab the attachement id's, throw them into an array to build proper links that know which spot they are in. I don't have an answer for you but you want to use `get_children` and some php iteration.

Comment: I looked into this further the currently functionality is broken if you use `[gallery]`, this trac ticket was closed http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22829 but the function `adjacent_image_link` does not work, I suggest you create a new trac ticket.

Comment: can you link to the full code for your attachment template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These functions will help:

```
//function to get next or previous keys in an array
function array_navigate($array, $key){
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $index = array_flip($keys);
    $return = array();
    $return['prev'] = (isset($keys[$index[$key]-1])) ? $keys[$index[$key]-1] : end($keys);
    $return['next'] = (isset($keys[$index[$key]+1])) ? $keys[$index[$key]+1] : current($keys);
    return $return;
}

function previous_attachment_ID($att_post){
    //get the attachments which share the same post parent
    $images =& get_children('post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&output=ARRAY_N&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC&post_parent='.$att_post->post_parent);
    if($images){
        //get the id of the previous attachment
        $ppid_arr = array_navigate($images, $att_post->ID);
        $ppid = $ppid_arr['prev'];
        return $ppid;
    }
    return false;
}

//previous attachment link function
function prev_att_link($att_post=null){
    if($att_post == null){
        global $post;
        $att_post = get_post($post);
    }
    $ppid = previous_attachment_ID($att_post);
    if($ppid != false){
        return '<a href="' . get_attachment_link($ppid) . '" class="previous-attachment-link">Previous</a>';
    } else {
        //there is no previous link
        return false;
    }
}

function next_attachment_ID($att_post){
    //get the attachments which share the same post parent
    $images =& get_children('post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&output=ARRAY_N&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC&post_parent='.$att_post->post_parent);
    if($images){
        //get the id of the next attachment
        $ppid_arr = array_navigate($images, $att_post->ID);
        $ppid = $ppid_arr['next'];
        return $ppid;
    }
    return false;
}

//next attachment link function
function next_att_link($att_post=null){
    if($att_post == null){
        global $post;
        $att_post = get_post($post);
    }
    $ppid = next_attachment_ID($att_post);
    if($ppid != false){
        return '<a href="' . get_attachment_link($ppid) . '" class="next-attachment-link">Next</a>';
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}

//back to gallery link function
function back_to_gal_link($text="Back to gallery"){
    global $post;
    $post = get_post($post);
    $post_par = get_post($post->post_parent);
    $slug = get_permalink($post_par->ID);
    return '<a href="'.$slug.'">'.$text.'</a>';
}


//show all thumbnails function
function show_all_thumbs() {
    global $post;
    $post = get_post($post);
    $images =& get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&output=ARRAY_N&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC&post_parent='.$post->post_parent);
    if($images){
        foreach( $images as $imageID => $imagePost ){
            if($imageID==$post->ID){
            } else {
                unset($the_b_img);
                $the_b_img = wp_get_attachment_image($imageID, 'thumbnail', false);
                $thumblist .= '<a href="'.get_attachment_link($imageID).'">'.$the_b_img.'</a>';
            }
        }
    }
    return $thumblist;
}
```

With this you can implement a previous next setup as you wanted, and, you can show all the thumbnails in the gallery.

e.g.:

```
<div class="back_to_gal_link">
    <?php
    echo back_to_gal_link().'<br />';
    ?>
</div>
<div class="prev_next_links">
    <?php
    if(prev_att_link()){
        echo prev_att_link();
    }
    if(prev_att_link() && next_att_link()){
    //insert a seperator between the two links
        echo ' | ';
    }
    if(next_att_link()){
        echo next_att_link();
    }
    ?>
</div>
<div class="thumbnails">
    <?php
    echo show_all_thumbs();
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: tested and works? btw: inside `array_navigate()` you could grab the index via `array_values()`, which should be slightly faster than flipping it.

Comment: 1. show_all_thumbs always shows the same thumbnails, no matter which thumbnails are in the post.
2. How do you prevent it from being an endless loop? That is, how would I make sure the last image does not have a "next" link on it?

Comment: The show thumbs bit shows all the images in the gallery, so it will always be the same. It's a form of quick navigation ( and also an optional one that is a side bonus, but not necessary to answer this question )

Comment: And yes, this is from a theme I had that I never released. To prevent the looping, you would need to modify array_navigate to return false rather than call end/current. You'd then ened to check for that false in `previous_attachment_ID` and `next_attachment_ID`. However doing that is beyond the scope of your question

Comment: In that case, your answer did not address my original question - as it does not allow the normal gallery display to only show images in the current gallery.  The traditional gallery insert still loops through images which are not in the post.

Comment: Take a look here http://themeforward.com/demo2/?p=2173 only 3 images should be in the gallery, yet many more are being linked to.

Comment: I see a gallery of 3 images. I see no thumbnails, or back to gallery link. Whatever you're trying to demonstrate its not at that link

Comment: On a sidenote, are the 3 images in the gallery the only images attached? Aside from the featured image. Or did you attach lots, but only put 3 in the gallery?

Comment: Also does my code give you what you want? **Ignoring the thumbnails again they are beyond the scope of this question**

Comment: I was editing the theme while you viewed.  Your code did not work.  For example; view this post http://themeforward.com/demo2/?p=2177 and you will notice only four images have been attached.  Click the flowers, now click the next link.  Where did the jellyfish come from!?  Your code did not solve this problem.  The Jellyfish was never attached to the post.

Comment: Some debug data will be necessary to continue. `global $post; echo '<pre>'.print_r( get_children('post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&output=ARRAY_N&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC&post_parent='.$post->post_parent).'</pre>';`

Comment: Where should I paste this: the image.php or single post template?

Comment: attachment/image template

Comment: Looks like the debug code is causing an error http://themeforward.com/demo2/?attachment_id=2147

My entire markup can also be found here: http://snippi.com/s/9on87jq

Comment: missed a closing bracket

Comment: I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: see how I do print_r( get_children( '..... ' ).'</pre> ? see how I close the get_children brace but not the print_r brace?

Comment: try this:`global $post; echo '<pre>'.print_r( get_children('post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&output=ARRAY_N&orderby=m‌​enu_order&order=ASC&post_parent='.$post->post_parent),true).'</pre>';`

Comment: The code is now live: http://themeforward.com/demo2/?attachment_id=2147

Comment: More specifically, inside the gallery: http://themeforward.com/demo2/?attachment_id=2147

Comment: oh dear: [post_parent] => 0 this is bad! Basically something went wrong before this point and the post parent was lost of misinterpreted, hence the reason for your problems

Comment: I'll need to sit on this for a little bit and figure it out, not in the best place to read code at the moment

Comment: No problem Tom, take your time, I sincerely appreciate the help.